# find child property key value and return parent object if value is true LODASH

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Give this data.
I am trying to return all data.objects who where property canHaveCookie : true

```
data : {
    name1: {
        canHaveCookie: true,
        anotherProp : false
    },
    name2: {
        canHaveCookie: false,
        anotherProp : false
    },
    name3: {
        canHaveCookie: true,
        anotherProp : false
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
var dataAttrObj     = grandparent.data,
    tmpProcessObj   = [];

tmpProcessObj = _.pickBy(dataAttrObj, function(item) {
        console.log('item is', item);
        return _.includes(item, {canHaveCookie: true});
        // console.log('objs here',  _.has(item, {canStopProcessing: true}) );
        // return _.some(item, {canStopProcessing: true});
        // _.some(item, {canHaveCookie: true}));
        // return _.has(item, ['canHaveCookie', true]);
        return _.includes(item, {canHaveCookie: true});
    });
```

What I expect to get is

```
data : {
    name1: {
        canHaveCookie: true,
        anotherProp : false
    },
//notice name2 is not here because name2 canHaveCookie is false
    name3: {
        canHaveCookie: true,
        anotherProp : false
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion using lodash?

Comment: `Object.keys` + `Array.prototype.reduce` do what you need `(:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use  [`pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#pickBy) is lodash, then you just need to check in the function if `canHaveCookie` is true. The first parameter to the function is the current value, so you simply need to return its canHaveCookie key (as it will be truthy if it is true).

For example:

```
_.pickBy(object, value => value.canHaveCookie)
```

Snippet:

```js
var obj = {
  data: {
    name1: {
      canHaveCookie: true,
      anotherProp : false
    },
    name2: {
      canHaveCookie: false,
      anotherProp : false
    },
    name3: {
      canHaveCookie: true,
      anotherProp : false
    }
  }
}

var result = _.pickBy(obj.data, value => value.canHaveCookie)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! 
So return value.canHaveCookie; ... is returning truthy for whether or not it should be picked?

Comment: FYI -- if you can't use ES6, 
var result = _.pickBy(obj.datj, function(value) {return value.canHaveCookie; });